# How can I separate in lines many mixed Integers, Floating points and Strings in a .txt file?

Tags: java

This is my first question in StackOverflow, I'm a beginner programmer who is currently learning, and unfortunately, my teacher is horrible.

I have a text file with a lot of Integers, Floating points and Strings mixed together, the part about identifyng each of then is okay, the main problem is separating then so then I can identify. I don't know how to do that.

My teacher gave me this scope for creating the code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Trabalho {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ler();
    }

    public static void ler() {
    try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line;
            in.
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                tratar(line);
            }
            in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    }

    public static void tratar(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many ways you can do this. We don't know what you learned already.

Comment: @M. le Rutte that`s the problem, he is a substitut teacher... and he is famous for being a baad teacher. Believe me, I would already have done that if it was a possibility

Comment: have you searched online for things like "parse string into float java", "parse string into int java", "difference between float and int java"?? Something you have recently found out, is that your teachers may not teach you everything you need to do the course work. It's times like these that you should start practicing finding information on your own,  there is plenty of examples out there that can help answer this question. good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I used this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LendoRockyYou {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ler();
    }

    public static void ler() {
    int total = 0;
        try {    
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\rockyou.txt"));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        total = total + tratar(line);
                System.out.println(total);
            }
            System.out.println(total);
            in.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Arquivo .txt não encontrado");
    }
    }

    public static int tratar(String text) throws IOException {
        int total = 0;
        try{
            total = total + Integer.parseInt(text);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            total = total + 0;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

I used the class FileReader to read the text file and fortunately the lines were already separated.

That was my main problem and about identifying the variables I used the parsing methods that I already knew.

Thats it, thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a problem all you need to do is break it into smaller pieces, this kind of mentality is what you will/should develop. As for an anwser, is better for you to find out by your own, and to think a little IMO. But the questions are: 1. How do you identify a Integer. 2. How do you identify a Float. 3. How do you identify a String.

Hope it helps.